# Facebook login not working with facebook application

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am coding for the `Login with the Facebook` into my android application.I am following this [STEPS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/).

I have problem that The **logout** button is not showing after login, it still displayed me **login** button. This problem is occure when I install the facebook app into emulator, but without install facebookapp it's working.

[image: Login button]

**After install Facebook Application :**

[image]

1. Press on the login button(From my application)
2. If not login then redirect to the facebook app
3. After login into facebook app back to my app and don't show me logout button but instead of  logout it show me login button

**Without install Facebook app :**   [This is working as I want]

[image]

1. press the login button(from my application)
2. Redirect to the facebook page (I don't know about this page)
3. After login success back to my app, and show logout button.

[image]

Now In short, I want second senario same for the First Senario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH while facebook.authorize

```
facebook.authorize(HomeTab.this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,new Facebook.DialogListener() {
```

As you can see third parameter use FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please tell me where I have to add this?

Comment: you havent shown any code, check in authorization with facebook, else post your code that you are using while login

Comment: ohh it luks like they have changed the code and process,, will take a look at this again and let you know

Comment: I am coding from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/

Answer (score 0):

old but, in section with 
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
add

```
authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```