# Facebook SDK 3 for Android - Login using facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

Now that I added a facebook LoginButton in my app to allow login with Facebook. 
The 'default' behavior is like this (I didn't do much modifications):

Scenario (A)
If the user has the official facebook app installed, it will call the app, login automatically , and show a dialog asking for permission. 
Scenario (B)
Or else if the user doesn't have the facebook app, a web page (like WebView) will pop up, ask the user to login, then ask for permission via the web interface.

It acts like this: [Facebook login not working with facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557247/facebook-login-not-working-with-facebook-application)

My app works PERFECTLY on AVD emulator for both scenarios, but "Scenario (A)" DOESN'T WORK ON my ACTUAL DEVICE. After logging in, It shows

[image]

Does anyone face the same problem? Is there a way to solve the issue? 
Or is there a way FORCE the app to perform login using the web interface?

Thank you so much!

Here are the Java and XML Layout codes:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_loginBtn);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email", "read_friendlists"));
    authButton.setOnErrorListener(fbErrorListener);
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(callback);

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
                xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/fb_loginBtn"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/reg_fb"
                fb:login_text="Facebook" />
```

Comment: Did you use your keyhashes right ? 
I got always 2 keyhashes:
in emulator - debug version, another one for device - release.

Comment: And maybe FB app on device is too old ? I got some client he has an old app preinstalled on his android device, so it was similar behavior.

Comment: The FB app is new... However I don't know if I'm using the correct keyhash, I am using the one located at C:\User\myname\.android\debug.keystore What shall I use instead? Thanks.

Comment: If you build signed app package (apk), than upload somewhere on web or sdcard for testing on real device - you need to use on FB dev page keyhash from release keystore, If you run via adb-wifi or similar on real device, debug.keystore must be ok, just like for emulator.

Comment: What I'm doing is simply connect the phone with a USB cable, use the wi-fi for Internet connection, and click the "debug" button in eclipse. I used debug.keystore to generate the key and copy it to facebook app page. Is it the right way? Please advise and thanks!

Comment: you're doing right: 1)get key hash from debug keystore; 2)using debug build.I was facing problem when testing signed apk for release (after debugging, where it was all ok) using keyhash from debug keystore in FB dev app settings. So problem is not in keyhash, it's all I can say so far :(

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe this is a bug from FB SDK then...

Comment: No problem ;) sometimes it happens

Answer (score 0):

it's not recommended to use only web
but if it's really needed:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
//other code ...
authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to allow auto-login when the user has already logged in facebook?

Comment: cant say exactly, but if I remember well, we had an app with web fb login, and we have not this feature; userflow was: user click login with fb butoon, then fb web login popups, he enters credential, we have set remember email option, and later on we remember user until he logged out or reinstall app or just clean all app data in setting.

Comment: probably You cant, because popup is webview, user wasnt logged in there before, as he is using external browser for using his facebook.

Comment: You're right! The WebView has its limitation... In fact the LoginButton was great until I found that it doesn't work on an actual phone...  I don't love the WebView one...

Comment: did you see my comments below your question? maybe it helps, just recheck all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly update your installed facebook application. As per my work experience Facebook SDK openGraph supports **facebook app version 1.9.8 to current version**.